# Best shape of wall

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

Suppose i have a wave(assume sine shape)moving across the surface of a fluid. Now i want to place an obstacle at a point in its path. What is the best shape of such a wall, to effectively stop that wave. Also the reaction to the wall should be minimum.

Comment: Have a look at "coastal defences" on the Internet to see what is done on a large scale. Here is an example http://www.se-coastalgroup.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Coastal-Defences.pdf

Comment: I AM talking about the curvature of the wall, which will make it most efficient. Are vertical walls the best for the purpose? I hardly think so. Anyways that pdf was informative.

Comment: A guess would be the equivalent of a pebble beach?

Comment: Pebbles are smoothened out by waves over time. They are streamlined over time. I dont thinl they are the best shape to stop a wave.

Comment: You are right but you need to dissipate the energy of the waves and do not want the wave to be reflected. Don't peddles on an incline do this?

Comment: Ah , i see what you mean. But then, a wall whose face matches the contour of the forward segment of the incoming wave is best?

Comment: A solid wall will reflect the wave.